# Incorrect Lightning record page shown for users

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-cache, lightning-record-page

We have a profile called as "Consumer Banker", and Consumer Banker profile has the "Consumer Individual Record Page" assigned for the App + Record Type + Profile combination. The Org Default is actually the "Account Record Page". There is a LWC on the Consumer Individual Record Page, which helps the Consumer Banker in booking an appointment.

**Issue** : In our Prod environment the Consumer Banker user will be logging in through SSO, initially for some days the Consumer Banker is getting redirected to the correct lightning record page i.e; Consumer Individual record page. After some days the Consumer Banker Users are reporting that they are unable to see the Appointment booking button, what's happening in the background is somehow the users are getting redirected to the "Account record page", which doesn't have the LWC on it.

Without doing any action from our side, after some days the Consumer Banker Users are reporting back saying that they are able to see the Appointment Booking button now. We are not sure of why the users are getting redirected to the Account record page instead of Consumer Individual Record Page.

**Troubleshooting steps which are done already**

1. Removing the browser cache
2. Logging in through different browsers and different machines
3. Logging in through incognito mode

None of the above troubleshooting steps helped, and the affected users are still getting redirected to org default page

4. Though it isn't recommended we have tried by disabling the checkbox "Enable secure and
   persistent browser caching to improve performance" under session settings. It actually worked
   when we asked the user to close the browser and login again. The user is able to see the
   appointment booking button now, but we can't keep the lightning cache disabled forever as it
   affects the performance for end users.

It would be great if anyone could throw some inputs on why this issue has been happening. We are thinking to unassign the org default page, and see if that helps with this issue but not quite sure whether that would fix anything.

Comment: @Phil The profile for that particular users does not have the permission to create account records directly. It seems lightning cache is causing the trouble, as disabling the option under session settings is resolving the issue

Comment: I have seen that the lightning cache is retained after page layout changes (on objects) so layout changes are not visible without a delay (or by turning off the session cache like you mentioned). I haven't seen it affect the lightning record page content before that I remember.